# How to make table rows/cells have the same fixed height without inner div in it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some kind of "menu", but my menu items have too large heights in IE. Tested it on chrome, firefox and safari and it's working fine. What's wrong with my code? Please help. I just want them to be "fixed" 2em in height, is it possible in ie? And I wonder, is it an error in my page or just an IE bug?

```js
window.onload=init;
window.onpageshow=init;
function init()
{
    var main=document.getElementById("mainview");
    var str=String.fromCharCode(Math.round( Math.random()*(90-65))+65);
    var chr;
    for(var i=0;i<20000;i++)
    {
        chr=String.fromCharCode(Math.round(Math.random()*(122-97))+97);
        if(chr!="<") str=str+chr;
        if(Math.random()<0.02) 
        {  chr=". "+String.fromCharCode(Math.round(Math.random()*(90-65))+65);
        }
        if(Math.random()<0.2) 
        {  str+=" ";
        }
        str+=chr;
    }
    main.innerHTML=str;
}
```

```css
table
{    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
tr.first
{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 2em;
}
tr.space
{
    height: 1em;
}
td.lmargin
{
    width: 3em;
}
td.label
{
    width: 10em;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #c30425;
}
td.menu
{
    padding-left: 2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 2em;    
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
td.dummy
{
    height: auto;
}
td#mainview
{
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="first">
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="label">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="space">
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td class="menu">
            Menu item 1
        </td>
        <td rowspan="6" id="mainview">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td class="menu">
            Menu item 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td class="menu">
            Menu item 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td class="menu">
            Menu item 4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td class="menu">
            Menu item 5
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="lmargin">
        </td>
        <td class="dummy">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm, which version of IE your using ?

Comment: It's a table?? How are you expecting each cell in the left column of a table to only be 2em tall when the content in the right cell is longer?

Comment: Version: 11.0.9600.17801

Comment: I expect the last cell at the bottom to have the height required to fill the space left (as it's done in the chrome, ff, safari). let me make a simple example to explain that: http://jsfiddle.net/BbIKTOP/s75wvqo8/5/
So, I expect the "menu" cell to be 2em tall and "dummy" cell to be as high as it's necessary to make it the same height as the "mainview" cell that is "rowspanned" to all these rows.

Comment: Marked it green: http://jsfiddle.net/BbIKTOP/s75wvqo8/6/

Answer (score 1):

Update: found the reason

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2312750

***The ROWSPAN property is disabled in Internet Explorer 8 if a webpage contains a  tag in a table cell***

It seems IE does not allow right cell to be larger than the left cell. Open developer console on IE (press F12) change

```
<td id="mainview" rowspan="6">
```

to

```
<td id="mainview" rowspan="1">
```

and see the differences.

Comment: No, sorry, just look here, it's not disabled and spanned ok: http://jsfiddle.net/BbIKTOP/s75wvqo8/7/
And I use ie 11

Comment: Lol sorry the link might not relate. Anyway, in IE the right cell's height will over write the height you have on the left. Test it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_height

I don't have a solution here unless you have a 2nd CSS which increase the height of dummy cell by (left cell height - 2em*5). You can vote down my answer above then.

Comment: Why, it's a kinda answer anyway ) 
Yes, I found it first, that IE cannot render table with "rowspanned" cells at the left. But now it looks like IE cannot renter tables properly at all. And sadly, I need this crap to be working on ie9. Have to cry a while ))
Thank you for your help.